Kids movie from early 2000's revolving around magic
I've been trying to think of this movie for a long time. It's a live-action kids' movie from the early 2000s that I believe revolved around magic. It was in English. I remember the kids getting trapped inside this house that's filled with magic things. The only two scenes that I can really think of are

when one the girls goes into the bathroom and the room starts spinning. She was on a black and white tile floor. 
Another scene I remember was one of the boys farts inside a trash can and can't get the trash can off afterwards. 

I wanna say that the title had the name "Houdini" in it, but I've looked all over for movies with that name in the title, and still cannot find it.

I have not seen the movie, but after searching "movie with kids trapped in magic house" in Gooogle, I found a movie that matches the description you gave. It is named "Spooky House" from 2002 starring Ben Kingsley as a reclusive magician with his house full of tricks and illusions. 
It is on vimeo: https://vimeo.com/82288272. I skipped around and found 2 scenes that mostly match what you remember, although the bathroom scene is actually just a room with a black-and-white spiral that starts spinning. 
